# Confusing C++ Loops

Tags: c++, loops

I'm trying to create the following structure for a C++ program in the terminal:

```
Menu:
   [1] Add Number
   [2] View Numbers
   [3] View Average

[CHOICE 1] 
   - Add a Number to array
   - Once finished, show Menu again so user can select another action
[CHOICE 2] 
   - View all numbers in array
   - Once finished, show Menu again so user can select another action
[CHOICE 3] 
   - View average of all numbers in array
   - Once finished, show Menu again so user can select another action
```

I'm not sure exactly how to set this up. When the user inputs each menu item's respective number, the corresponding information appears. That's easy enough, using if statements to look for the user's inputted number.

However, my problem comes when I try to show the menu again so the user can select another action. I recognize some sort of loop is necessary here but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Can you help me set up a basic structure of how to start this? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: This should be relatively simple. What have you tried?

Comment: Look up basic flow control in your textbook. For, while, do while, if, if-else, switch, etc. You should be able to find what matches your needs the best.

Comment: Add a choice "[4] Exit" and then, Put all your main code into a while(choice!=4){ALL YOUR MAIN CODE HERE}

Comment: Right now I'm just using if statements to check for what menu option the user inputted.

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether you use `if ()` or `switch ()` to check the selected option. In the end bot will create similar code.

Comment: You should look at looping structures available in C++. I would use a `while` loop to solve this problem myself.

Comment: Place the menu into a loop and then create a class which allows one to modify numbers in the array, view the numbers, and then calculate and view the averages. Try adding the numbers to a vector and then storing it as a variable in the class, which other class functions work upon. I know this seems like some advanced stuff, but view some tutorials on how to use vectors. They function like arrays, and have a lot of tools useful for calculating averages and such.

Comment: I'll have to do some more studying on this stuff apparently. :) Thanks for the help y'all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break down your menu entries into functions to keep everything clean and easy to grasp (for now).

This can be expanded a lot, creating some kind of menu handling etc, but I'd just stick to something like this:

```
void mainmenu() {
    int choice;
    do {
        std::cout << "Menu\n[1] -> Add Number\n[2] -> View Numbers\n[3] -> View Average\n[0] -> Quit" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice;
        // now perform actions based on the choice
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            addanumber();
            break;
        case 2:
            printnumbers();
            break;
        case 3:
            printaverage();
            break;
        }
    } while (choice); // loop as long as the choice isn't 0 (i.e. user wants to exit)
}
```

As Kerrek mentioned in a comment, this doesn't really check whether the user actually picked any integer value at all. This makes the code a bit more complicated, but in general would be good practice (as thing scan get nasty, if you ignore such things):

Replace `cin >> choice;` above with this:

```
if (!(std::cin >> choice)) {
    choice = -1; // if input provide an invalid choice so the menu just shows again
    // also clear the input buffer of leftovers
    std::cin.clear(); // clear the buffer
    std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n'); // read any leftover chars till a line break (user hit return key)
}
```

Comment: This code is broken. It's UB to read `choice` if the input operation didn't succeed. The same thinking error is at the core of about 90% of all C++ SO questions :-( ...and now you've just taught another poor shlub the same mistake.

Comment: The `do ... while()` will make the menu reappear again, just as Kerrek's `for()`. Pick whatever loop you've learnt already.

Comment: yay, I've just been called a shlub. ;)

Comment: @codedude: Only conditionally, and if I ever see a question of yours that abuses an input operation or calls `eof()`. Until then you're fine in my book :-)

Comment: @Mario: Test it! In particular, the program must survive a Ctrl-D, or equivalently `echo "" | ./prog` must behave sanely. (My money is on "no".)

Comment: It "kinda" works. ;) The only issue has been the length of `-1` (which didn't eat any chars (so obviously taking a signed integer for me). Only downside to this solution, you either catch line breaks or end of file, but not both.

Answer (score 3):

Factor the code into separate functions:

```
enum Action { AddNumber, ViewNumbers, ViewAverage, Quit, Error };

Action show_menu_and_read_user_input();   // write this!

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    for (bool again = true; again; )
    {
        switch (show_menu_and_read_user_input())
        {
            case Error:
                std::cout << "Sorry, I did not understand.\n";
                break;

            case Quit:
                std::cout << "Goodbye!\n";
                again = false;
                break;

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is clearly a beginner question, so I guess this might be a bit overkill handling this with an `enum`, etc.

Comment: yeeaaahhh...I haven't gone over enum yet.

Comment: It's just a "list", you could replace the `enum` elements with numbers/integers any time, e.g. replacing `Error` with `1` and `Quit` with `0` (and skipping the `enum` line).

Answer (score 3):

At the very basic level...

```
for(;;)
{
    // Display the menu
    cout << "Menu:\n"
            "   [1] Add Number\n"
            "   [2] View Numbers\n"
            "   [3] View Average\n";

    // Ask user for input
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    // Take action
    if( choice == 1 ) {
        // ...
    } else if( choice == 2 ) {
        // ...
    } else if( choice == 3 ) {
        // ...
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid choice\n";
    }
}
```

This is an infinite loop, because your menu does not appear to have an 'exit' option.  I have laid this out with `if` statements instead of a `switch`, because as a beginner it's easy to get confused by `switch` and accidentally end up with problems.

One step at a time =)

Comment: This is undefined behaviour when the input operation fails.